Нужна запятая в сложном предложении с союзом ЛИ...ИЛИ?
Мы не знали, туда ли мы идём(,) или всё дальше уходим от истинного пути.
Это сложноподчиненное предложение СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. Ставится ли запятая перед ИЛИ в таком сложном предложении? Почему?

думаю не нужна. Мы не знали - относится в равной степени к обоим придаточным.

Да? Но это же сложное предложение, а у Розенталя написано,что в сложном ставится запятая. Интонация опять же смущает: есть там пауза или нет? И вы все-таки обозначали бы в ответе вашу позицию для ясности, я тогда учту ваше мнение. А когда в СПП ставится запятая, вы не могли бы привести пример?


Союзы ли…или рассматриваются как повторяющиеся, а потому придаточные части сложноподчиненного предложения, связанные этими союзами, разделяются запятой: И долго все присутствовавшие оставались в недоумении, не зная, действительно ли они видели эти необыкновенные глаза, или это была просто мечта… (Г.); …Налево всё небо над горизонтом было залито багровым заревом, и трудно было понять, был ли то где-нибудь пожар, или же собиралась всходить луна (Ч.); После этого решится, будет ли он воевать, летать, жить, или ему будут вечно уступать место в трамвае и провожать его сочувственными взглядами


Это вы имеете ввиду? Значит надо, наверное)

Не знаю... А пауза в моем предложении есть или нет?  Какое-то  оно неправильное...  Я его у Солоухина позаимствовала, только немного переделала.

Ну Розенталь считает, что ли-или - это два союза в связке и между ними нужна запятая. Наверное, он прав. Но вы же знаете, что при желании можно и без запятых писать, звучит это странно, иногда разговорно, но лучше ставить запятую, если нет причин каких-то веских её не ставить. Может, можно разорвать связку,  и "ли" сделать отдельным от или... 0
Мы не знали, туда ли, мы идём верно или всё дальше уходим от истинного пути.

Считайте, что вы на ЕГЭ,  Это такая тема, где за неправильные запятые по головке не погладят) Так какой ваш окончательный ответ? //
Вот предложение у Солоухина: Так шли мы часа два или более, не зная, туда ли идем, куда нужно, или все дальше, непоправимо дальше уходим от истинного пути.  // Но он «ушел» и от этой запятой тоже.

"Но он «ушел» и от этой запятой тоже." - )))
